# How I can build a table in matlab with the following values?

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and do not know how to make a table that compares the values  of this polynomial function with w=1/(x^2+1)

my attempt

```
 x= [-5,-3,-1, 1, 3,5]

 x =

-5    -3    -1     1     3     5

y= [0.0385, 0.10, 0.50, 0.50, 0.10, 0.0385]

y =

0.0385    0.1000    0.5000    0.5000    0.1000    0.0385

yp=[0.0148,0.06,0.50,-0.50,-0.6,-0.0148]

yp =

0.0148    0.0600    0.5000   -0.5000   -0.6000   -0.0148

hp = hermite (x, y, yp )

hp =

-0.0000   -0.0000    0.0001    0.0004   -0.0011   -0.0100    0.0072    0.0969   -0.0113   -0.4156    0.0051    0.8282
```

Now it only remains to compare in a table the values of hp with w.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please do not use the [homework] tag anymore; it's in the process of being removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no `w` in your question, but in general the expression

```
hp == w
```

will, if the vectors have the same length, return a vector of `0`s and `1`s, of that length, representing the cases where the two vectors match (`1`) or don't match (`0`).  In passing, note that comparison for equality of floating-point numbers is fraught with 'issues' and you might be better evaluating:

```
abs(hp-w) < 10^-6
```

replacing `10^-6` by your preferred tolerance.

Given your definition for `w` you should be able to write

```
hp == 1/(x.^2+1)
```

Note the use of the elementwise squaring operator `.^`, which returns a vector of the same length as `x` with each element the square of the corresponding element in `x`.  Of course, the expression

```
hp - 1./(x.^2+1)
```

will return a vector of the differences, which might be what you want.

Comment: You need a `.` after ` as well: `1./(x.^2+1)`. Also, I think `hp` has a different size than `x` in OPs case. At least it seems so from the data in the post.

Comment: Thanks @angainor, I've updated the last code fragment.  I'll leave OP to sort out the mismatched lengths, (s)he should be able to figure it out.